# Is <option> layout "magic"?

Tags: css, select

Can CSS achieve the same layout as `<option>`?

[image]

The presence of `<option>` does not affect the scroll of the containing scroll area, and appears outside the containing scroll area.

This seems to be a very "magic" layout, since I cannot figure out to have any other sort of element have the same layout.

---

EDIT: Example of native select https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWJrqR

Can the dropdown box layout be replicated with CSS?

Comment: position you custom *option container* `absolute` with respect to the dropdown?

Comment: Can you do code in codepen and send me link I will fix your problem.

Comment: @RajeshKumarSah https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWJrqR

Comment: Hey using ul li you can make a dropdown and that will help you to fixed your problem using position.

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is that the layout of the select options box is indeed not possible to product via only CSS.

The closest you get is using JS to hook the scroll handler.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJMpGB

```html
<section id="container" class="container">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
  <p><strong>Select</strong></p>
  <div id="options-container" class="options-container">
    <div class="options">
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
      <p>Three</p>
      <p>Four</p>
      <p>Five</p>
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
      <p>Three</p>
      <p>Four</p>
      <p>Five</p>
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
      <p>Three</p>
      <p>Four</p>
      <p>Five</p>
      <p>One</p>
      <p>Two</p>
      <p>Three</p>
      <p>Four</p>
      <p>Five</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</section>
```

```css
.options {
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.options-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 30;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
}

p {
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('container')
  .addEventListener('scroll', event => {
    document.getElementById('options-container').style['transform'] =
       'translateY(' + -event.target.scrollTop + 'px)';
  });
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work very well in browsers that use asynchronous scroll handlers; you can see the scroll box jumping around a little while scrolling.